# No Preview available when I load without .pdf content webview

Tags: java, android, pdf, webview

I try to load my contant as PDF in webview android but it display No Preview Available How can i solve 
My Code is Here :-

```
webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    String URLPATH = "http://myaccount365.in/public/oddeve78/report/ledger/11/summaryLedger?fromDate=01/11/2019&toDate=09/12/2019";
    String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + URLPATH;
    webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is clearly this:

You have two URLs - the URL of the PDF and the URL of google docs. Since you want to pass one URL to the other URL as a *GET parameter* (`?embedded=true&url=`) and the URL that you try to pass **contains GET parameters as well**: `?fromDate=` and `&toDate=`, the seconds URL has to be *URLEncoded*.

So please just call

```
String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + URLEncoder.encode(URLPATH, "ISO-8859-1");
```

and try again.

**Caution**: when working with URLEncoder.encode: you always have this problem: you can either call the `@Deprecated`  method `URLEncoder.encode(String s)` without a specific encoding or the preferred method with `URLEncoder.encode(String s, String enc)` where you can specifiy the encoding, but this method has `throws UnsupportedEncodingException`  in its signature :-O

Anyhow, both `URLEncoder.encode(url)` and `URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8")` or `URLEncoder.encode(url, "ISO-8859-1")` will yield the same result since you have no UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 specific characters in the URL:

https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmyaccount365.in%2Fpublic%2Foddeve78%2Freport%2Fledger%2F11%2FsummaryLedger%3FfromDate%3D01%2F11%2F2019%26toDate%3D09%2F12%2F2019

Answer (score 2):

I'm using this and works for me: [Check Here](http://weimenglee.blogspot.com/2013/05/android-tip-displaying-pdf-document.html)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WebView webView=new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    //---you need this to prevent the webview from
    // launching another browser when a url
    // redirection occurs---
    webView.setWebViewClient(new Callback());

    String pdfURL = "http://www.expertagent.co.uk/asp/in4glestates/{16D968D6-198E-4E33-88F4-8A85731CE605}/{05c36123-4df0-4d7d-811c-8b6686fdd526}/external.pdf";
    webView.loadUrl(
            "http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + pdfURL);

    setContentView(webView);
}

private class Callback extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(
            WebView view, String url) {
        return(false);
    }
}
```

OR Try

I think Exact Problem is in URL encoding which we concat with `"http://docs.google.com/gview?url="`. This means we have to replace all special character(:, /, & etc) of url with `unicode`. `Uri.encode("")` do the trick for us.

Like this

```
String url = Uri.encode("your link");
String finalUrl = "http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + url + "&embedded=true";
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your pdf file URL problem, please check your `URLPATH` it wether return a pdf URL like this `https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_tutorial.pdf`

I use this URL it render normal

```
String URLPATH = "https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_tutorial.pdf";
String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + URLPATH;
//url:https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_tutorial.pdf
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  String URLPATH = "http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf";
  String url = "https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + URLPATH;
  webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: It's not working again give No Preview Available display

Answer (score 0):

I think your URLPATH is a dynamic url, it return a file url according to the params. but now it may be not return a correct url. it can to check it, or you change the URLPATH to a url which has `http://host:port/path/.pdf` . use it to test your code.